# Error CA0063 : * Failed to load rule set file Kentor.AuthServices.ruleset' or one of its dependent rule set files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, code-analysis

when I build the project (visual studio 2019) in debug mode , I am getting this error but the web application launches fine .

```
Error CA0063 : * Failed to load rule set file Kentor.AuthServices.ruleset' or one of its dependent rule set files.
```

however when I debug it in release, no build errors

any idea how to get rid of this error in debug mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Project Properties/Code Analysis, then re-add `Kentor.AuthServices.ruleset` or remove it.

[image]

Comment: I tried this , but I cannot find this ruleset (Kentor.AuthServices.ruleset) in dropdown nor when i browse it !

Comment: You can switch it to other default ruleset, if you don't need `Kentor.AuthServices.ruleset`.